# can i save the output of opencv VideoWriter to AWS S3 storage?

Tags: python, opencv

Hi i am trying to save the output of Opencv VideoWriter to AWS S3

but this code seems not work.

Do you have any idea to change the path of VaideoWriter output???

'''code

```
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')

    AWS_path = 'https://bucket.s3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/media/video/'
    filename = 'temporary_video.mp4' 
    pull_path = AWS_path + filename        

    out = cv2.VideoWriter(pull_path, fourcc, fps, (int(width), int(height)))

    while (cap.isOpened()):
        hasframe, frame= cap.read()

        if hasframe== True:
            # print('떠라')
        # if hasframe is None:
            datum = op.Datum()
            datum.cvInputData = frame
            opWrapper.emplaceAndPop([datum])

            # Display Image
            # print("Body keypoints: \n" + str(datum.poseKeypoints))
            # print("Face keypoints: \n" + str(datum.faceKeypoints))
            # print("Left hand keypoints: \n" + str(datum.handKeypoints[0]))
            # print("Right hand keypoints: \n" + str(datum.handKeypoints[1]))

            # cv2.imshow("OpenPose 1.5.0 - Tutorial Python API", datum.cvOutputData)
            # cv2.waitKey(1)

            out.write(datum.cvOutputData)
        else:
            break
    cap.release()
    out.release()
```

Comment: Can you add a more detailed error description than "not work"?

Comment: Thank you for comment, this code is proceeded without any error message. But, in AWS S3 storage, there is no output file. It seems VideoWriter cannot find the path.

Comment: You should add that to your question.